# How to quickly toggle the HUD+Weapon in Doom 2016 (without going into Options)

Tags: doom-2016

Doom 2016 is such a beautiful game. I like taking snapshots of the scenery, but always have a bigass gun and reticle in the way. Is there a way to quickly disable the HUD and hide the weapon, do a screenshot, and then re-enabling the HUD? Maybe a console command?

I don't want to delve into the Options every time... "aint nobody got time fo' that!".

Comment: In the days of Quake3 Arena, there was something like `cg_drawviewmodel 0`, I could imagine that this still works, but sadly can't recall the exact command.

Comment: is it even possible to hide a weapon?

Comment: Not that I know of...